# Understanding GWT-RPC Concept

Tags: gwt, gwt-rpc, gwt2, gxt

Can anybody explain me about this thing?

X-GWT-Permutation:1F79347D29BC07C95FC8B3A262D5DC8E

i have tried decoding some of the strings using Base 64.

i am using the following base to decode strings like bwR2, bwSo, bwSn, bwTU...

Base = "ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZabcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz0123456789$_

i got this string from this type of Request Payload Header:

7|0|10|https://www.bosscapital.com/app/Basic/|B8CC86B6E3BFEAF758DE5845F8EBEA08|com.optionfair.client.common.services.TradingService|prepare2OpenPosition|J|D|java.lang.String/2004016611|I|1.11427|0|1|2|3|4|11|5|5|5|5|6|6|7|7|8|7|8|BHLE|**bwRF**|E|Po|1.11427|1.11427|9|0|49|10|1|

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `X-GWT-Permutation` header references a GWT permutation's strong name (the strong name is an MD5 of the generated JavaScript code out of the `JavaToJavaScriptCompiler`, before it gets passed to the "linker").
The value isn't actually checked, only the presence of the header (as a partial countermeasure against XSRF).

The GWT-RPC wire protocol is described in https://drive.google.com/open?id=1eG0YocsYYbNAtivkLtcaiEE5IOF5u4LUol8-LL0TIKU